# Django : How to get all data related to logged in user

Tags: django, django-views

I want to create a view that returns all data from a model related to the currently logged-in user.

eg i have a model that has a relationa to the User table set belo in user_rel :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class ProcessInfo(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    user_rel = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I want to write a view and this is what I have :

```
def processList(request):
    user_pk = request.user.id
    processess = ProcessInfo.objects.get(user_rel=user_pk)
    context ={
    'processess':processess,
    }
    return render(request, 'process/process_list.html', context)
```

I am expecting a list of all processes inserted by the currently logged in user. How do I fix this vew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) the `QuerySet`, instead of using [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get), since the latter retrieves *one* object and if there are no objects, or multiple ones, it will error:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def processList(request):
    processess = ProcessInfo.objects.filter(user_rel=request.user)
    context ={
        'processess':processess,
    }
    return render(request, 'process/process_list.html', context)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).